# Display multiple list in django template

Tags: python, django

I have 10 lists of same lenght (20) with chained data meaning that A[0] is image for B[0] and C[0] but for the sake of smallest reproducible example i have 3

```py
A=[image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6]
B=[title1, title2, title3, title4, title5, title6]
C=[name1, name2, name3, name4, name5 ,name6]
```

I need to dispaly them in Django Templates like this:

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="image">
                image1
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                title1
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                name1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="image">
                image2
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                title2
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                name2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="image">
                image3
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                title3
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                name3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and after this row is next one will be generated with the rest of the values

**How can i do this**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip`

**Ex:**

```
def yorufunc(request):
    A=[image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6]
    B=[title1, title2, title3, title4, title5, title6]
    C=[name1, name2, name3, name4, name5 ,name6]
         
    context = {"data": zip(A, B, C)}
    return render(request, 'yorufunc.html', context)
```

In Template

```
<div class="row">
    {% for i, t, n in data %}
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="image">
                {{ i }}
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                {{ t }}
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                {{ n }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: is there any other option?

Comment: Another option would be to create a list of `dict` in the view and send it to the template

Answer (score 0):

another way would be, by using index templatetags

in your app folder create one folder, named `templatetags`

there create a file `index.py` :

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def index(indexable, idx):
    return indexable[idx]
```

now it's better to restart your server once.

then in html do:

```
{% load index %}

<div class="row">
    {% for x in A %}
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="image">
                {{x}}
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                {{ B|index:forloop.counter0 }}
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                {{ C|index:forloop.counter0 }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```